# Session write timeout issue in Apache Ignite

Tags: java, multithreading, ignite, gridgain

We are doing a load test on Apache Ignite.

We have 1 DB server and 1 tomcat's App server.

Both machines have this setup.

```
CPU Intel I7
Speed   2.6Ghz
Cores   4
Ram 16GB
Disk 500GB
```

Configuration ->

```
App server Java Heap -> Xms512m, Xmx3072m.
DB server Java Heap -> Xms512m, Xmx3072m.
DB server persistence -> true
DB server Offheap Max size -> 3072m.
Write throttling enabled.
Client failure detection timeout set to 10000ms
Failure detection timeout set to 30000ms
Query thread pool size is the default -> 8
```

Scenario ->

Via the tomcat App server, I have started 500 threads that run a business logic to set and get data from Ignite. Code-wise, there is semaphore locking for cache access and threads usually are being in blocked state as other threads are using the resources. After running for say 3-4 hours, the App server has thrown a warning mentioned below.

```
"org.apache.ignite.logger.java.JavaLogger" "warning" "WARNING" "" "294" "Communication SPI session write timed out (consider increasing 'socketWriteTimeout' configuration property) [remoteAddr=xxxxx/xxxxx:47100, writeTimeout=2000]" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "" "ROOT" "{""service"":""xxxx"",""logger_name"":""org.apache.ignite.spi.communication.tcp.TcpCommunicationSpi""}"
```

I've also seen quite a few "Possible too long JVM" prints before that print showing around 500ms to 1000ms delay.

After the execption is thrown, few minutes later, the client got disconnected and queries thrown this error ->

```
org.apache.ignite.internal.IgniteClientDisconnectedCheckedException: Query was canceled, client node disconnected.
```

While it was running fine, I enabled JProfiler just to see how it's running in App server JVM and I could see a lot of threads being in "Blocked" state. And since it's 4 core machine, I can see a max of 12-15 app server threads being executed at a time (using logical cores). And then quit the profiler and let it run for 2-3 hours until the exception occurred.

Although in real-time, we won't spawn those many threads, and in production, we will have 100s of cores on Servers, it's important for us to understand how we can set up a deployment that will scale up to meet the need of spawning many threads.

Can someone please explain?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like long GC causing client node to segment. What's the longest "Possible too long JVM pause" message? Have you tried increasing `failureDetectionTimeout`? Decreasing heap size of client nodes?

Comment: Hi Alamar! We got like 2769ms delay as the highest recorded! But we got like 400 too long pause prints which are mostly around 500ms. I believe this failureDetectionTimeout is for server-server timeout delay right? it's 30seconds.. We didn't try increasing. And why should we decrease client's heap size? what it'll do?

Comment: Normally you would decrease the value of `-Xmx` with which you run the client.
It will also make sense to get a heap dump of node once you see first "too long" messages, see if there are any obvious memory leaks.

Comment: Will check dump once.. I actually started server by decreasing client -Xmx to 2048m.. Also i increased failuredetectiontimeout.. been 2 hours and didn't receive any exceptions. But I don't think these two are issues here.. What I want to say is as it's a 4 logical core machine and it's executing 500 threads almost parallel because I made cache level semaphore synchronization, the whole process is getting slow.. even the CPU percentage is constantly at 80-90%.. Do you think I run tests on a machine having more cores?

Comment: I'm not sure if having more cores will help. Maybe you should have fewer threads, altough 500 is not a huge number in practice.